# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que una cadena pase a entero en C++?

Tags: c++

Tengo una suma de dos fracciones en string, ejemplo: 2+2 en cadena de texto, pero quiero convertirlo a entero y me dé el resultado de esa misma que sería 4.

Ya intenté con métodos como `stoi()`, `atoi(.c_string)`, y con `if(istringstream() >> )` pero parece que no me funciona. ¿Alguna idea sencilla?

Comment: Esas funciones cumplen bien su cometido. Convierten una cadena de caracteres en un número. Lo que **no** hacen es evaluar expresiones algebraicas. Tendrás que programar algo o si prefieres usa una librería.

Answer (score 0):

Las funciones disponibles en la librería estándar no van a evaluar una expresión matemática en formato cadena de texto ... pero si puedes extraer los números y hacer tu la operación:

```
std::string operacion = "2+2";
std::stringstream ss(operacion);

int numA, numB;
char operando;

ss >> numA >> operando>> numB;

int resultado = 0;
switch(operando)
{
    case '+':
        resultado = numA + numB;
        break;
    case '-':
        resultado = numA - numB;
        break;
    case '*':
        resultado = numA * numB;
        break;
    case '/':
        resultado = numA / numB;
        break;
}

std::cout << resultado;
```

Para resolver operaciones más complejas tendrás que implementar un mecanismo un poco más completo